# Autohotkey Mapping Modifiers

Tags: autohotkey

I can't use arrow keys from my keyboard so I mapped 1234 to be the arrow keys like that:

```
*!^1::
   Send, {Left down}{Left up}
Return

*!^2::
   Send, {Down down}{Down up}
Return

*!^3::
   Send, {Up down}{Up up}
Return

*!^4::
   Send, {Right down}{Right up}
Return
```

Now my problem is that in some programs the arrow keys pressed with the shift modifier is associated to a function and with the current settings, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> it still outputs me the associated arrow key without considering the 'Shift' modifier.
Do you know how could I solve the problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a list of commands that already includes the shift key, like this:

```
*+!^1::
   Send, {Shift down}{Left down}{Left up}{Shift up}
Return

*+!^2::
   Send, {Shift down}{Down down}{Down up}{Shift up}
Return

*+!^3::
   Send, {Shift down}{Up down}{Up up}{Shift up}
Return

*+!^4::
   Send, {Shift down}{Right down}{Right up}{Shift up}
Return
```